# Flutter Failed to upload Multiple images obtained from multi_image_picker

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I've been successful in obtaining multiple images using the multi_image_picker but failed to upload the images to firebase storage. Am requesting for help as regards saving the images to firebase storage and returning the urls.

Ive posted my code below, Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
import 'package:mock_data/mock_data.dart';



class PageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<PageTwo> {
  List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
  String popop = mockString(50);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Future saveImage(Asset asset) async {
    String fileName = popop;
    ByteData byteData = await asset.requestOriginal();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putData(imageData);

    return await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
  }

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
          maxImages: 300,
          enableCamera: true,
          selectedAssets: images,
          cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
          materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
            actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
            actionBarTitle: "Example App",
            allViewTitle: "All Photos",
            selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
          ));
    } 
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
      _error = error;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Getting pics'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Pick images"),
              onPressed: loadAssets,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Save Image"),
              onPressed: () => saveImage,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: buildGridView(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually doing anything with the URL. Your Future on saveFile doesn't return anything, nor are you placing the result anywhere.

```
await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL()
```

Plus, that looks a bit odd to be awaiting an await. You could probably get away with simply cascading the onComplete await. I'm not entirely sure but worth a try.

```
await uploadTask.onComplete..ref.getDownloadURL()
```

Furthermore, when I use StorageUploadTask I usually listen to the task to get upload progress and then I add the onComplete portion to get the downloadURL.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me.